# Retrieving data from SQLite by clicking Login button values can't be replaced

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created 2 accounts, yes it will display the values to the next screen but my problem is after signing out my 2nd account I tried to login the 1st account I made but the values displayed are still on my 2nd account informations. I need your help guys. Do I need to create a new copy of a database?

DatabaseHelper.java

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contacts.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "contacts";
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String COLUMN_PASS = "pass";
private static final String COLUMN_MOBILE = "mobile";
SQLiteDatabase db;

private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table contacts(id integer primary key not null ,"+
        "name text not null, email text not null, pass text not null, mobile text not null);";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
    this.db =db;
}

public void insertContact(Contact c){
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    String query = "select * from contacts";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();


    values.put(COLUMN_ID,count);
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME,c.getName());
    values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL,c.getEmail());
    values.put(COLUMN_PASS, c.getPass());
    values.put(COLUMN_MOBILE, c.getMobile());

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    db.close();
}

public List<Contact> getAllData() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "select name, email, mobile from contacts";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setName((cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setEmail(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setMobile(cursor.getString(2));

            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return contactList;
}

public String searchPass(String email){
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "select email, pass from " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    String a, b;
    b = "not found";
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            a = cursor.getString(0);

            if(a.equals(email)){
                b = cursor.getString(1);
                break;
            }
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return b;
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME;
    db.execSQL(query);
    this.onCreate(db);
}
```

Profile.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profileview);

    TextView vName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    TextView vEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
    TextView vMobile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMobile);
    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    try {
        List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllData();
        for (Contact cn : contacts) {
            String name = cn.getName();
            String email = cn.getEmail();
            String mobile = cn.getMobile();
            vName.setText(name);
            vEmail.setText(email);
            vMobile.setText(mobile);
            // follow by getEmail and getMobile
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast pass = Toast.makeText(Profile.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        pass.show();
    }

    Button btnOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOut);
    btnOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent Outent = new Intent(Profile.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(Outent);
            finish();
        }
    });

}
```

Login.java

```
DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    Button createAccount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignup);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edEmail);
            String str = a.getText().toString();
            EditText b = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edPassword);
            String pass = b.getText().toString();

            String password = helper.searchPass(str);
            if (pass.equals(password)) {

                Toast pasa = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                pasa.show();

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Profile.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast temp = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Email and password don't match!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                temp.show();
            }
        }
    });

    createAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent newIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SignUp.class);
            startActivity(newIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: You need to associate some column in your database with what account each contact belongs to. Yes, there is only one database that is used by "each user" of your app. You won't have "one per login"

Comment: change your query as you are getting all data using getAllData();
and setting the last value 
so your query will be 
SELECT name FROM UnknownTable WHERE rowid = 1;

Comment: In your for loop you are setting vName and vEmail in every iteration. Eventually the last one will be shown i.e. the second one for our case.

Answer (score 0):

HI use where condition for displaying login account data. please check below

// pass name or email that you use for login

```
 public List<Contact> getAllData_BY_NAMEOREMAIL(String name) {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();

       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

         Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select name, email, mobile from contacts WHERE name = ?;",
                    new String[] { name });

       // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setName((cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setEmail(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setMobile(cursor.getString(2));

                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        return contactList;
    }
```

Comment: I think `name` is the name of a contact, not the currently "signed in user". In other words, that where condition would only return one row. (Assuming unique names)

Comment: Pass current login user email or name (that you use for sign in) by intent.

Comment: name is a currently sign in user name.

Comment: (I didn't ask the question) How do you know that `name` is the signed in user? And if it was, then query doesn't make sense in terms of a "contact book"

Answer (score 0):

your function will be by using id

```
public Contact getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query("contacts", new String[] {"name", "email",
"mobile" }, "id" + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setName((cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setEmail(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setMobile(cursor.getString(2));


    return contact;
}
```

Comment: You called `new Contact` twice, by the way

Answer (score 0):

Please make your table schema Id based primary key like:
make 2 ids for both account and insert data where id = account id and also fetch data where id = account id.